# NA and NaN in Pandas column: Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, nan, na

I have a Pandas column which contains NAs, NaNs, and floats (the dtype of the column  is 'Object'). I am struggling to convert the NAs to NaNs. I want to replace the NAs with NaNs and then change the column dtype to float.

I have tried using various methods to replace the NAs. For example:

```
df.data.astype('float', inplace=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: NA

df.data[df.data == 'NA'] 
Series([], Name: data, dtype: object)  # empty
```

I have also tried using the na_values='NA' param when reading the csv. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
df.data = pd.to_numeric(df.data, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'NA', 6, 7, 'NaN', 'Stuff'], columns=['Col1'])

rem_fields = (r'[^.0-9]')

rep_with = (np.nan)

df['Col1'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=rem_fields, value= rep_with)

print df
```

'rem_fields' tells pandas to replace anything that's not a digit or '.' with NaN

This is the output:

```
   Col1
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   NaN
6   6.0
7   7.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
```